# Getting the selected index while using ng-options

Tags: angularjs

Using [this Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xH9Uc/1/), how can I move the second (closest to the bottom of the `SELECT`) "green" item up and down using the Up and Down buttons?  If the second "green" item is selected and either button is pressed then it is the first "green" item that moves, which is incorrect.  All the other items behave correctly.

In general, my question is how to identify a specific item in a `SELECT` using `ng-options` if the list can contain multiple copies of the same object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both "green" elements have same id in your code which creates some confusion (since the id is the parameter that identifies a specific element, so same id means same element), if you are talking about 2 different elements with same name just change the id of one of them and everything works fine

e.g :

```
$scope.list = [
    { id: 100, name: 'blue' },
    { id: 101, name: 'green' },
    { id: 102, name: 'red' },
    { id: 104, name: 'green' },
    { id: 103, name: 'yellow' }
];
```

Comment: Yes, they have the same id, but they are two distinct elements in the `SELECT`.  The first "green" has a `value` of 1 and the second has a `value` of 3 (their array indexes).  The question is, how can I get which one is currently selected?

Comment: This is not what your code says when you use this condition to get the index : if( a[i].id == item.id ); [id is not unique in your code so this condition is not good] while looping the id matches the first element so the function returns the index of the first element instead of second which leads to : 1- Change the id as I suggested; or 2- Change the way you get the indexes

Comment: I agree, the example is very contrived, but it is intended to illustrate the problem. The question is about "Getting the selected index" using AngularJS.  In vanilla javascript you can do: `document.getElementById(id).selectedIndex` and maybe that is the only answer here as well.